# Is it possible to save pdf document to byte array (aspose.pdf for java)

Tags: java, pdf, arrays, aspose, aspose.pdf

I need to save a pdf document, generated by `aspose.pdf for java` library to  memory (without using temporary file)

I was looking at the [documentation](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/pdfjava/Concatenate+PDF+Files) and didn't find the `save` method with the appropriate signature. (I was looking for some kind of outputstream, or at least byte array).

Is it possible? If it is, how can I manage that?

Thanks

Comment: maybe this can help you: http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/326929/how-to-write-pdf-stream-to-pdf-file.aspx

Comment: also this may work too: http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/pdfjava/Create+a+Hello+World+PDF+document+through+API

Comment: Thanks, but the first link about C#, I'm using java. In the second they are using `pdf1.save("HelloWorld.pdf")`, but I'm looking for something like `pdf1.save(outputStream)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Aspose.Pdf for Java supports saving output to both file and stream. Please check following code snippet, It will help you to accomplish the task.

```
byte[] input = getBytesFromFile(new File("C:/data/HelloWorld.pdf"));
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
com.aspose.pdf.Document pdfDocument = new com.aspose.pdf.Document(new ByteArrayInputStream(input));
pdfDocument.save(output);
//If you want to read the result into a Document object again, in Java you need to get the
//data bytes and wrap into an input stream.
InputStream inputStream=new ByteArrayInputStream(output.toByteArray());
```

I am Tilal Ahmad, developer evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for!

Answer (score -1):

I did similar thing.

Here is method to write data to byte:

```
public byte[] toBytes() {
        //create byte array output stream object
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        //create new data output stream object
        DataOutputStream outStream = new DataOutputStream(byteOutStream);
        try {//write data to bytes stream
            if (data != null) {
            outStream.write(data);//write data
            }//return array of bytes
        return byteOutStream.toByteArray();
    }
```

Then you do something like

```
yourFileName.toBytes;
```

Comment: I was looking for the solution for the *specific* library in this case (`aspose.pdf for java`), which saves documents as files on a hard drive using  the following method: `pdfFile.save("/name/of/the/file.pdf")`. I was expecting the solution with outputstream as the parameter.

Comment: Did you encounter any issue while using ByteArrayOutputStream object as shared by Tilal above. In case you are facing any problem, please share your resource files by posting query in Aspose.Pdf product support forum.